# Linear mapping on a Banach space that composition is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

Let X,Y and Z be Banach spaces. Suppose $F\subset B(X,Y)$ has the property that $Tx=0$ for all $T\in F\implies x=0$. If $S:Z\rightarrow X$ is a linear mapping such that $TS\in B(Z,Y)$ for all $T\in F$, show that $S\in B(Z,X)$.

I have worked out a way below: If a linear functional is bounded, then it is continuos at 0. Then we assume that it is not bounded, then there is a sequence $\{x_n\}$ converges to 0 that $S(x_n)$ doesn't converges to 0. But $TS(x_n)$ converges to 0 implies that $s(x_n)$ converges to 0 by the condition it provided for F. This is a contradiction. However, I didn't apply X,Y and Z are complete. So what's wrong with my proof? And how to produce a correct proof?

Comment: This isn't correct. The hypothesis says nothing about convergent sequences.

Comment: Try to apply the closed graph theorem (this requires $X$ and $Z$ complete, completeness of $Y$ is indeed not needed).

Comment: Thanks. I think I get the answer.